# IF string contains 'XX' then change color...Write_rich_string to Panda Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have about 7 dfs that are saved and write to individual sheets within an excel workbook. They are currently doing so using openpyxl. I found this code which does almost exactly what I am looking for - the issue is that if I replace the 'sequences = .....' with 'sequences = df' which is the name of my dataframe, the data is not populating correctly..

Ultimately I have 7 dfs that I am trying to put on this 1 workbook (on different sheets), some with this condition, some with other conditions and some without conditions. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this properly? I am still learning

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('sequences.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
green = workbook.add_format({'color': 'green'})

sequences = [
    'ACAAGATG',
    'CCATTGTC',
    'CCCCGGCC',
    'CCTGCTGC',
    'GCTGCTCT',
    'CGGGGCCA',
    'GGCCACCG',
]

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)

for row_num, sequence in enumerate(sequences):

    format_pairs = []

    # Get each DNA base character from the sequence.
    for base in sequence.upper():

        # Prefix each base with a format.
        if base == 'A' or base == 'T':
            format_pairs.extend((red, base))

        elif base == 'G' or base == 'C':
            format_pairs.extend((green, base))

        else:
            # Non base characters are unformatted.
            format_pairs.append(base)

    worksheet.write_rich_string(row_num, 0, *format_pairs)

workbook.close()
```

This is the output of df:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H65ky.png)

This is what I get in excel file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAlzA.png)

Comment: In the code you've got here, `sequences` is a list, not a dataframe. You'd need to convert the dataframe to a list if you want to use the same code.

Comment: is there any way to convert the list code to a dataframe code? @miken32